# Как вставить картинку в шестиугольник svg?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, img

У меня есть кастомная рамка - шестиугольник, и я хочу вставить В него картинку, но она просто на него накладывается сверху.

```html
<svg width="70" height="64" viewBox="0 0 70 64" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
                        <g filter="url(#filter0_d)">
                        <path d="M21.433 55.4987L7.86603 32L21.433 8.50129H48.567L62.134 32L48.567 55.4987H21.433Z" stroke="url(#paint0_linear)" stroke-width="1.5" />
                        </g>
                        <defs>
                        <filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0.751282" width="70" height="62.4974" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                        <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
                        <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                        <feOffset/>
                        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.5"/>
                        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.980392 0 0 0 0 0.760784 0 0 0 0 0.0745098 0 0 0 1 0"/>
                        <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                        <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                        </filter>
                        <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="33.7826" y1="57.1282" x2="33.7826" y2="4" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <stop stop-color="#F4AC26"/>
                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FDCB0C"/>
                        </linearGradient>
                        </defs>
                    </svg>
```

Comment: Приложите код к вопросу

Comment: в вашем случае pattern -  читайте документацию

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/XWNdwRr - вот так примерно

Answer (score 5):

Изображение можно вставить в любую рамку с помощью:

1. clipPath
2. mask
3. pattern

### #1. clipPath

Изображение добавляется в SVG с помощью тега - **[image](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/image)**

И обрезается с помощью **clipPath** по форме шестиугольника, заданной в `path` секции `defs`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 200 174.284" > 
    <defs> 
     <!-- Форма шестиугольника по которой будет обрезано изображение -->
    <clipPath id="cp">  
    <path  fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"  d="M139.854 14.087H60.146A4.024 4.024 0 0056.66 16.1L16.806 85.129a4.025 4.025 0 000 4.025l39.854 69.03a4.026 4.026 0 003.486 2.012h79.708a4.026 4.026 0 003.486-2.012l39.854-69.03a4.025 4.025 0 000-4.025L143.34 16.1a4.024 4.024 0 00-3.486-2.013z"/> 
    </clipPath>
    </defs>  
       <!-- Добавление изображения в SVG --> 
      <g clip-path="url(#cp)">
    <image width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/686/800/800"   />
    </g>  
    
       <!-- Внешняя Рамка, при необходимости можно удалить -->
    <path  fill="none" stroke="#989064" stroke-width="4"  d="M139.854 14.087H60.146A4.024 4.024 0 0056.66 16.1L16.806 85.129a4.025 4.025 0 000 4.025l39.854 69.03a4.026 4.026 0 003.486 2.012h79.708a4.026 4.026 0 003.486-2.012l39.854-69.03a4.025 4.025 0 000-4.025L143.34 16.1a4.024 4.024 0 00-3.486-2.013z"/> 
  </svg>
```

### #2. mask

Более функциональный вариант, при котором возможны многочисленный варианты обработки изображения:

1. Вырезать изображение по форме шестиугольника при path `fill="white"`
2. Сделать изображение полупрозрачным при выборе заливки маски промежуточного значения от белого до чёрного цвета
3. Убрать, добавить рамку, сделать её  полупрозрачной

Ниже пример с вырезкой изображения `fill="white"` и полупрозрачной рамкой `stroke="red" stroke-width="6"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 200 174.284" > 
    <defs> 
     <!--  fill="white" Форма шестиугольника по которой будет вырезано изображение --> 
     <!-- Рамка сделана полупрозрачной stroke="red" stroke-width="6" -->
      
    <mask id="msk">  
    <path  fill="white" stroke="red" stroke-width="6"  d="M139.854 14.087H60.146A4.024 4.024 0 0056.66 16.1L16.806 85.129a4.025 4.025 0 000 4.025l39.854 69.03a4.026 4.026 0 003.486 2.012h79.708a4.026 4.026 0 003.486-2.012l39.854-69.03a4.025 4.025 0 000-4.025L143.34 16.1a4.024 4.024 0 00-3.486-2.013z"/> 
    </mask>
    </defs>  
       <!-- Добавление изображения в SVG --> 
      <g mask="url(#msk)">
    <image width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/686/800/800"   />
    </g>  
  </svg>
```

### #3. pattern

При этом варианте изображение загружается в `pattern` секции `defs`, а затем паттерном заполняется фигура svg - `<path fill="url(#img1)"`

В примере ниже одним и тем же изображением заполняются квадрат, окружность, треугольник

```html
<!-- http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/path-pattern-fill.svg -->
<svg     
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="600" height="450" viewBox="0 0 600 450" >
     
    <title>Заполнение изображения в разные формы SVG</title>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="450">
            <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFlxC.jpg" x="0" y="0"
                width="600" height="450" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M5,50
             l0,100 l100,0 l0,-100 l-100,0
             M215,100
             a50,50 0 1 1 -100,0 50,50 0 1 1 100,0
             M265,50
             l50,100 l-100,0 l50,-100
             z"
          fill="url(#img1)" />
        
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

*Вопрос изменен после появления первого ответа.*
*Поэтому новый ответ.*

К шестиугольнику применены сложные фильтры, градиенты, но это не помешает добавить к нему изображение по **3 варианту с паттернами**.

```
<defs>
    <!-- Добавляем изображение к шестиугольнику fill="url(#img1)"> -->
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
           <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFlxC.jpg" x="0" y="0"
              width="600" height="450" />
        </pattern>
</defs>
```

```html
<svg width="70" height="64" viewBox="0 0 70 64" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
                        <g id="path1" filter="url(#filter0_d)" fill="url(#img1)">
                        <path d="M21.433 55.4987L7.86603 32L21.433 8.50129H48.567L62.134 32L48.567 55.4987H21.433Z" stroke="url(#paint0_linear)" stroke-width="1.5" />
                        </g>
                        <defs>
                        <filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0.751282" width="70" height="62.4974" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                        <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix" />
                        <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                        <feOffset/>
                        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="3.5"/>
                        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.980392 0 0 0 0 0.760784 0 0 0 0 0.0745098 0 0 0 1 0"/>
                        <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                        <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                        </filter>
                        <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="33.7826" y1="57.1282" x2="33.7826" y2="4" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <stop stop-color="#F4AC26"/>
                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FDCB0C"/>
                        </linearGradient> 
                        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="600" height="450">
                         <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFlxC.jpg" x="0" y="0"
                           width="600" height="450" />
                        </pattern>
                        </defs> 
                        
                    </svg>
```

Следующий пример адаптивен к любому гаджету и добавлено изменение внешнего вида шестиугольника при наведении мыши

- Для адаптивности убираем из шапки SVG `width`, `height`

  Оборачиваем svg в родительский div и задаем ему размеры в
  относительных единицах

Для изменения внешнего вида шестиугольника анимируем у фильтра `feflood` атрибут `flood-opacity="0.15"`

```
    <!-- Анимация цвета фона при наведении                        -->
      <feFlood flood-opacity="0.15" result="BackgroundImageFix" > 
        <animate attributeName="flood-opacity" begin="svg1.mouseover" dur="0.3s" 
          to="0.75"  fill="freeze" end="svg1.mouseout" />
      </feFlood>
```

```html
<style>
 .container {
 width:15vw;
 height:auto;
 }
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1"  viewBox="0 0 70 64" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
                        <!-- Добавляем изображение к шестиугольнику -->
                        <g id="path1" filter="url(#filter0_d)" fill="url(#img1)">
                        <path d="M21.433 55.4987L7.86603 32L21.433 8.50129H48.567L62.134 32L48.567 55.4987H21.433Z" stroke="url(#paint0_linear)" stroke-width="1.5" />
                        </g>
                        <defs>
                        <filter id="filter0_d" x="0" y="0.751282" width="70" height="62.4974" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
                         <!-- Анимация цвета фона при наведении                        -->
                       <feFlood flood-opacity="0.15" result="BackgroundImageFix" > 
                          <animate attributeName="flood-opacity" begin="svg1.mouseover" dur="0.3s" to="0.75"  fill="freeze" end="svg1.mouseout" />
                        </feFlood>
                        <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0"/>
                                                
                        <feOffset/>
                        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="6"/>
                        <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 0.980392 0 0 0 0 0.760784 0 0 0 0 0.0745098 0 0 0 1 0"/>
                        <feBlend mode="normal" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="effect1_dropShadow"/>
                        <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_dropShadow" result="shape"/>
                        </filter>
                        <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="33.7826" y1="57.1282" x2="33.7826" y2="4" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <stop stop-color="#F4AC26"/>
                        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FDCB0C"/>
                        </linearGradient> 
                            <!-- паттерн для изображения -->
                        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
                         <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFlxC.jpg" x="0" y="0"
                           width="600" height="450" />
                        </pattern>
                        </defs> 
                        
                    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @Andrii Stehnii Если ответ вам был полезен, не забудьте поставить галочку и плюс